# Complicated subtraction in R

Tags: r, aggregate, cumulative-sum, split-apply-combine

I am working on a data-set that requires me to subtract information from columns. It is a repeated measure data-set where one person is tested up to a max of six times and a minimum of two times. The data are in long-format

Here's a sample data-set:

```
ID=c('X1', 'X1', 'X1', 'X1', 'X2', 'X2', 'X2', 'X3', 'X3', 'X3', 'X3')
Time=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4)
Score=c(10, 9, 8, 6, 10, 8, 4, 9, 8, 6, 4)
dat=data.frame(ID, Time, Score)
```

In its simplest form, my data contain the following variables:

- `Participant ID` - Unique alphanumeric code
- `Time` - Varying from 1-6
- `Score` - Scores on test 1 varying from 1-10. Scores may stay the same or decline over repeated tests.

I want to compute the difference between consecutive scores over testing sessions, add them up, and divide it by the number of scores each participant has. In simpler form, I would like it to look like this below:

```
Sum of [(time1-time2 score) + (time2-time3 score) + (time3-time4 score)]/N (Scores for participant)
```

The denominator would have to account for different numbers of repeated measurements per participant.

Earlier, my code was this:

```
S = length(unique(dat$ID))     
dat$ppt = as.numeric(factor(dat$ID, labels = 1:S))     
mat = matrix(nrow = S, ncol = 2) # empty matrix 

for (s in 1:S) { # for each subject 
  scores = dat[dat$ID == s, 'Score'] # get scores for participant s 
  scores = na.omit(scores) 
  avCumDiff = sum(diff(scores))/length(scores) # average cumulative difference 
  mat[s,] = c(s, avCumDiff) # add to matrix
}     
colnames(mat) <- c('ppt', 'AvDiff')
```

The problem with this code is that it cumulatively subtracts scores from one another. I want it to add the differences between scores 1&2, 2&3, 3&4 etc.

How do I do this best?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Comment: Not really a statistical question. Are data in a long or wide format. You should see `?diff` and `?rowSums`.

Comment: Try `library(data.table);setDT(dat)[, Sum:= sum(abs(diff(Score)))/.N, ID]`

Comment: Thanks @akrun. But R gives me an error. Error: could not find function "setDT"

Comment: You have to install `data.table`. i.e. `install.packages('data.table'); library(data.table)`

Comment: Hi @akrun, sorry I wasn't clear in my previous comment. I got that error after installing and calling the package

Comment: Which version do you have?  I have the devel version of data.table, but setDT should also work with the 1.9.4 CRAN version

Comment: Another option is using `ave` from `base R`.  `dat$Sum <- with(dat, ave(Score, ID, FUN=function(x) sum(abs(diff(x)))/length(x)))`  I hope it will work for you

Comment: Did it worked for you?

Comment: I'm running R studio 2.13.1 on a mac. Its not letting me install 'base' as well. Do I have to downgrade my R version for either of these codes to work?

Comment: **Surely `[(time1-time2 score) + (time2-time3 score) + (time3-time4 score)}` simplifies to `(time1 - time4 score)`** , unless you're using absdiff? So your computation is mostly unnecessary. You only need to know first score, last score, and number of attempts?

Comment: Also consider using a [`cumdiff` function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20746110/202229)

Comment: @smci you are right, it does simplify to time1-time4 score. However, the results I am getting are negative integers (which shouldn't be the case), considering scores either stay the same or decline. I'm not sure if my code doing what I intended it to do

Comment: When you say 'I want it to add the differences between scores 1&2, 2&3, 3&4 etc.' you mean **"sum the absdiffs in scores"**. Otherwise, the result  should indeed be negative if scores decline.

Answer (score 2):

It's a one-liner in dplyr (or data.table). Here's the dplyr version (akrun already gave you the data.table version):

```
require(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarize(avdiff = (last(Score)-first(Score)) / n() )

  ID  avdiff
1 X1 -1.00
2 X2 -2.00
3 X3 -1.25
```

or if you want absdiff, do `avdiff = abs(last(Score)-first(Score) / n()`

Most of your code was redundant and could be removed:

- Whenever you see `length(unique(dat$ID)` then iterate over those `1:S`, that's a strong code smell that you're doing a **`group_by(ID)`** i.e split-apply-combine, usually for an aggregation.
- Then slicing `scores = dat[dat$ID == s, 'Score']` was exactly that group_by operation. (By the way that always comes up empty, you meant `[dat$ppt == s, 'Score']`)
- Converting ID to a factor `dat$ppt = as.numeric(factor(dat$ID...` was totally unnecessary. `group_by(ID)` does that. It's ok for your group names or matrix rows not to be integers.
- Declaring an empty result `mat = matrix(...)` is unnecessary, as is manually inserting to it with `mat[s,] = c(s, avCumDiff)`
- `scores = na.omit(scores)` is unnecessary; most sum, cumsum, absdiff etc. functions exclude NA by default, the 'house style' in R functions is to be NA-aware and do the smart thing in the presence of NAs.
- So you wanted to aggregate absdiff of scores and divide by number of attempts.
- Note the use of dplyr's `first(Var), last(Var), n()` within a group
- Finally, `dplyr::summarize` allows you directly name your summary column(s), so you don't need `colnames(mat) <- c('ppt', 'AvDiff')`. When you do a `summarize` operation, the result you get is a df containing only the column used for grouping (ID), and the summary column (`avdiff`); the other variables `Time, Score` are dropped automatically.

Read about split-apply-combine, aggregation, dplyr or data.table tutorials, and try them out.