# In R, how can I count positions with a sliding window and then filter?

Tags: r, tidyverse

There are already several questions with sliding windows, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943428/sliding-window-in-r) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738461/fast-way-to-count-events-over-a-sliding-window), but I don´t figure my case out. I have a dataframe with a column `positions`. I want to use a floating window of 100 and identify all the windows containing at least 3 values for positions within the interval. My actual dataset is quite long, but let´s use the following reproducible example:

```
set.seed(0)
possible_values <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
col1 <- sample(possible_values, 17, replace = TRUE)
positions <- c(5,17,57,101,105,123,400,578,698,707,717,735,787,811,832,853,919)
df <- data.frame(col1, positions) 
> df
   col1 positions
1     B         5
2     A        17
3     D        57
4     D       101
5     B       105
6     B       123
7     D       400
8     C       578
9     D       698
10    C       707
11    D       717
12    A       735
13    B       787
14    A       811
15    C       832
16    B       853
17    A       919
```

I want to use a sliding window on the positions column with an interval of 100, and report which window includes 3 or more occurences of positions, with the start value of the window. Preferably using the tidyverse.
The expected results is:

```
col2 <- c(5,17,57,101,707,717,735,787)
count <- c(5,4,4,3,4,4,4,4)
expected <- data.frame(col2,count)
> expected
  col2 count
1    5     5
2   17     4
3   57     4
4  101     3
5  707     4
6  717     4
7  735     4
8  787     4
```

I have tried different codes, for example this, without the expected result:

```
> df_window_counts <- df %>% arrange(positions) %>%
     mutate(window_start = findInterval(positions, seq(min(positions), max(positions), 
        by = window_size))) %>%
     group_by(window_start) %>%
     summarise(count = sum(!is.na(positions))) %>%
     filter(count >= 3)
> df_window_counts
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  window_start count
         <int> <int>
1            1     4
2            8     4
3            9     3
```

I have also tried to use the slider package, but I don´t get there. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you open to a *data.table* solution? It will be something like `library(data.table); setDT(df); df[, pos100 := positions + 100]; df[df, on=.(positions>=positions, positions<=pos100), .N, by=.EACHI]` where you're essentially joining `df` back on itself and looking for records that are between `positions` and `positions + 100`.

Comment: I am not opposed to data.table solutions per se, but I am way less familiar with its syntax. I can give it a try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's (yet) a tidyverse function for sliding windows (though perhaps soon). Not "easy", that is.

Some suggestions:

## sapply windows

```r
df %>%
  mutate(
    count = sapply(positions,
       function(pos) sum(between(positions, pos, pos+100)))
  )
#    col1 positions count
# 1     B         5     5
# 2     A        17     4
# 3     D        57     4
# 4     C       101     3
# 5     A       105     2
# 6     B       123     1
# 7     A       400     1
# 8     C       578     1
# 9     C       698     5
# 10    B       707     4
# 11    B       717     4
# 12    C       735     4
# 13    C       787     4
# 14    A       811     3
# 15    A       832     3
# 16    A       853     2
# 17    B       919     1
```

## range-join

```r
df %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number(), rhs = positions + 100) %>%
  left_join(df, join_by(between(y$positions, x$positions, x$rhs)), suffix = c("", ".y")) %>%
  summarize(.by = c(rn, col1, positions), n = n()) %>%
  select(-rn)
#    col1 positions n
# 1     B         5 5
# 2     A        17 4
# 3     D        57 4
# 4     C       101 3
# 5     A       105 2
# 6     B       123 1
# 7     A       400 1
# 8     C       578 1
# 9     C       698 5
# 10    B       707 4
# 11    B       717 4
# 12    C       735 4
# 13    C       787 4
# 14    A       811 3
# 15    A       832 3
# 16    A       853 2
# 17    B       919 1
```